# Error when referencing these links

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

I have a document with a lot of sources, but when I added these 3 sources I seem to be getting errors.

```
@misc{opencv,
  author = {OpenCV},
  title = {Detection of Aruco Markers
},
  howpublished = {\url{https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html}},
  note = "[Online; accessed 16-March-2022]"
}


@misc{camcalib,
  title = {Detection of Aruco Markers},
  howpublished = {\url{https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html}},
  note = {Accessed: 2022-03-16}
}

@misc{unicycle,
  title = {The Unicycle Model},
  howpublished = {\url{http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/robotics_sg/Control/kinematics/unicycle.html}},
  note = {Accessed: 2022-03-16}
}
```

I have isolated the problem to these, since it is only when I add them that I get errors. I don't know why I'm getting these errors. I can't copy paste them all but here is an image of the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Latex code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=4cm}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
Må legge til senere, gjør ikke akkurat nå p.g.a klarhet
\usepackage{fullpage}
\end{comment}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}


\begin{document}


Text

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Doc_ref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that gives this error. We need to see the LaTeX code as well.

Comment: Try replacing the underscores (`_`) in urls with `\_`.

Comment: Added Latex text

Comment: @Imran That solved it, thanks!

Comment: @Robotnik Doing that won't produce the urls correctly in the document. If you use the `url` package (i.e. add `\usepackage{url}` in the preamble), then there will be no problem for such things and you won't need to edit the URLs manually.

Comment: Note that the `apacite` style supports a dedicated field for URLs called `url`. You get better results from using `url = {https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html},` instead of `howpublished = {\url{https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html}},`. Apart from that Imran's second comment is the answer: Load `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` (`hyperref` loads `url` and makes URLs clickable). (You should do that also when you use the `url` field)